# How to simulate Left click in WPF from inside the event handler of right click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, event-handling

How to simulate Left click in WPF from inside the event handler of right click

Actually problem is the grid cell is not getting selected by directly right lcik on it. 
If user first do a left click on grid cella nd then a right click then it works well.

So from inside the right click handler i want to first simulate the left click.
How to do this.

This is the right click event handler

```
void OnCFLgrdrightmouseclick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // usign the same sender and e i want to generate left click event first
  // and then remaining code should execute

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like, but you may have to guard for infinite recursion..

```
this.grid1 = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(target));
this.grid1.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(grid1_MouseLeftButtonDown);
this.grid1.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(grid1_MouseRightButtonDown);


void grid1_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if( leftClicked < (e.Timestamp - maxTimeBetweenClicks) )
   {
      MouseButtonEventArgs fakeLeftMouse = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.LeftButton);
      grid1_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender, e);
   }

   leftClicked = 0;
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void grid1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   leftClicked = e.Timestamp;

   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it. It's a design flaw. Define rather actions that you want to execute when real events happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MenuItemAutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.menuitemautomationpeer.aspx) for that:

```cs
MenuItemAutomationPeer peer = new MenuItemAutomationPeer(myMenuItem);
((IInvokeProvider)peer).Invoke();
```

**EDIT:**

But keep in mind that Bartosz Wójtowicz is right. You shouldn't use it in production code as it is not a good design. You can use it in testing code, so you won't have to change production code for testing purposes.